# From android.graphics.Path to ImageView

Tags: android, path, imageview

I have a android.graphics.Path variable which I want to convert into an ImageView in my activity.
What I do right now and does NOT work (but it does run without error, it just displays a blank activity) is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Path p = ... // some bezier curves
        PathShape pathShape = new PathShape(path, (float)20.0, (float)20.0);
        ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(pathShape);
        ImageView testImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.testImage);
        testImage.setImageDrawable(shapeDrawable);
    }

}
```

The corresponding activity_main.xml is:

`<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.tg.MindGames.set.MainActivity">`

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/testImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

`</RelativeLayout>`

What did I do wrong and what is considered best practice to put Path into an ImageView?

Additional Information: I want to use the Paths to draw the images of cards in a simple card game. Several cards and additional text fields should be displayed on the activity at the same time, cards should be able to have an onClickListener.
The size of 20.0 x 20.0 is arbitrary and should be altered later when I use the ImageViews in a GridView.

Comment: you have to sprcify correct Paint for your shape

Comment: I cannot figure out how to get from the Path to a Paint and from the Paint to a Drawable for the ImageView

Comment: see ShapeDrawable methods

Comment: Now I tried several things with Paints, ShapeDrawables, Canvas,... but nothing worked...can you please give me some example code?

Comment: tried ShapeDrawable.getPaint()?

Comment: what do I do with the Paint now?
And is there no other way to fill my ImageView with the Path?
My code so far:

`PathShape pathShape = new PathShape(path, (float)20.0, (float)20.0);

        ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable();

        shapeDrawable.setShape(pathShape);

                                          Paint a = shapeDrawable.getPaint();`

Comment: setColor,  setStyle. setStrokeWidth etc

Comment: Yes obviously but what then?
I am really new to this drawing stuff on Android and I can't figure out  the way to use the Path to get a Drawable.
Can't you just tell me step by step how to get a Drawable from a Path?

Comment: if you dtill dee noting try replace testImage.setImageDrawable with testImage.seBackgroundDrawable

Comment: does not work.
Does anyone have another idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so here you have a red triangle drawn on the view's background:

```
View v = new View(this);
Path path = new Path();
path.moveTo(0, 1);
path.lineTo(0.5f, 0);
path.lineTo(1, 1);
ShapeDrawable sd = new ShapeDrawable(new PathShape(path, 1, 1));
sd.getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
v.setBackgroundDrawable(sd);
setContentView(v);
```